# Finding the Missing Zero of the Quadratic

Tags: quadratics

Given that $ f(x)= ax^2+bx+c$, where $b = a + 1$ and $c=b+1$. One zero of the function is $x=6$. Find the other zero of $f$.

I actually have the answer to the question but only a brief explanation of some of the steps. If I define $R$ to be the missing root the question is calling for. I understand that $6R = \frac{a+2}{a}$, but why is $6+R=\frac{-(a+1)}{a}$?

When I attempted this problem by myself I thought $6+R = \frac{a+1}{a}$?

I am sure I am missing something very fundamental any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: By Vieta's formulas $6 + R = -b/a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:
$$(x-x_1)(x-x_2)=0$$
$$x^2-(x_1+x_2)x+(x_1.x_2)=0$$